# Local Tamagawa numbers for algebraic *surfaces*

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

If $X/\mathbf{F}_q$ were an algebraic curve with closed point $x$, and $G$ a smooth $d$-dimensional affine group scheme over $X$, then the Tamagawa measure $\mu_{\omega, x}$ for the locally compact group $G(K_x)$ would have
$$\mu_{\omega, x}(G(\mathcal{O}_x))\ =\ q^{-\deg(x)\nu_x(\omega)}\frac{\lvert G(\kappa(x))\rvert}{\lvert\kappa(x)\rvert^d},$$
where $\omega$ is an invariant top-degree form on $G(K_x)$. [See [Gaitsgory and Lurie - Weil's conjecture for function fields](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/tamagawa.pdf), page 11.]

Now take $X/\mathbf{F}_q$ to be an algebraic *surface* with point $x$ of codimension $1$; $G(K_x)$ is still locally compact, so we can define the local Tamagawa measure as before. However, $\kappa(x)$ is no longer finite. Is there an analogue of the formula above for $\mu_{\omega,x}(G(\mathcal{O}_x))$?